# How can a variable be not defined when it's literally defined above?

Tags: python, opencv, nameerror

```
haar_cascade=cv.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project-III\faces.xml')
people = ['ABC', 'XYZ','PQR']

file = open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\face.txt', 'a')

capture = cv.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
    isTrue,frame=capture.read()
    haar_cascade=cv.CascadeClassifier('faces.xml')

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
        faces_roi=gray[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(faces_roi)
        print(f'Label={people[label]} with a confidence of {confidence}')
        

    file.write(people[label])
    file.write(str(confidence))
    file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    file.write("\n")

    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF==ord('d'):
        break

cv.imshow('Detected faces', frame)
file.close()
cv.waitKey(0)
```

I get:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'label' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\Parth\Desktop\Project-III\face_recog_video_PROTOTYPE.py", line 41, in <module>
    file.write(people[label])
                      ^^^^^
NameError: name 'label' is not defined
```

How can `label` be not defined when it's literally defined above?

The code was running perfectly fine few minutes ago.

Comment: It indicates that the `for` loop executed zero times. We don't have your input data so we can't tell you anything more. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: If `faces_rect` is empty, `label` is never set

Comment: `label` is defined inside `for` loop, and you invoke it level above. You will get the same error with variable `confidence`. So you need initialize those labels before loop

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the value of a variable or subexpression is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: declared <> defined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
        faces_roi=gray[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(faces_roi)
        print(f'Label={people[label]} with a confidence of {confidence}')
        for i in range (0,cnt):
          cv.putText(frame, str(people[label]),(i*400,40), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.0, (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.rectangle(frame,(x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.imshow('video',frame)

    file.write(people[label])
    file.write(str(confidence))
    file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    file.write("\n")
```

label is defined inside the for loop, it could be that there are no `faces_rect` and label ends up not being defined.

Add print statements and check.

Maybe you wanted to indent the last part of the code?

```
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
        faces_roi=gray[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(faces_roi)
        print(f'Label={people[label]} with a confidence of {confidence}')
        for i in range (0,cnt):
          cv.putText(frame, str(people[label]),(i*400,40), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.0, (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.rectangle(frame,(x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.imshow('video',frame)

        file.write(people[label])
        file.write(str(confidence))
        file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        file.write("\n")
```